# Pandas .apply with conditional if in one column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe as below. I am trying to check if there is 0 or 1 in the vector column, if yes,
add 10 to the vector and divide by adding 2 to the vector otherwise keep the same vector.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user 1', 'user 2', 'user 3'],
                   'vector': [[0.01, 0.07, 0.0, 0.14, 0.0, 0.55, 0.11],
                              [0.12, 0.27, 0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.09, 0.19],
                              [0.58, 0.07, 0.02, 0.14, 0.04, 0.06, 1]]})
df
```

Output:

```
user    vector
0   user 1  [0.01, 0.07, 0.0, 0.14, 0.0, 0.55, 0.11]
1   user 2  [0.12, 0.27, 0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.09, 0.19]
2   user 3  [0.58, 0.07, 0.02, 0.14, 0.04, 0.06, 1]
```

I used the following code:

```
  df['vector']=df.apply(lambda x: x['vector']+10/(x['vector']+2) if x['vector']==0|1  else x['vector'], axis=1)
```

But the Output:

```
user    vector
0   user 1  [0.01, 0.07, 0.0, 0.14, 0.0, 0.55, 0.11]
1   user 2  [0.12, 0.27, 0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.09, 0.19]
2   user 3  [0.58, 0.07, 0.02, 0.14, 0.04, 0.06, 1]
```

The expected output:

[image: expected output]

Comment: `0+10/(0*2)` is not equal to `5`, did you mean `0+10/(0+2)`?

Comment: yes, sorry for that, i mean df.apply(lambda x: x['vector']+10/(x['vector']+2) if x['vector']==0|1  else x['vector'], axis=1)

Comment: Then 1 should give 4.333?

Comment: yes, that right

Answer (score 4):

Use a list comprehension (faster than `apply`):

```
df['vector'] = [[x+10/(x+2) if x in [0,1] else x for x in v] for v in df['vector']]
```

Output:

```
     user                                                   vector
0  user 1                 [0.01, 0.07, 5.0, 0.14, 5.0, 0.55, 0.11]
1  user 2                 [0.12, 0.27, 0.1, 0.14, 0.1, 0.09, 0.19]
2  user 3  [0.58, 0.07, 0.02, 0.14, 0.04, 0.06, 4.333333333333334]
```

Comment: @alxander21 sure, what would you want to do exactly?

Comment: @ mozway I want to normalize or clip the values that meet condition (0 or 1), so these values don't exceed one!

Comment: @alxander21, should negative values (e.g. `-0.2`) be also clipped to `0` ?